# trade flows with igraph package in r

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph

I have trade data (exports/imports) of 200 countries of a specific good. Example:

```
b <- c("countryA", "countryB", "countryC", "countryA", "countryC", "countryA")
c <- c("countryB", "countryC", "countryA", "countryB", "countryA", "countryB")
d<- c(100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 200)
e <- c(5,12,10,24,25,12)
mydata <- data.frame(b,c,d,e)
colnames(mydata) <- c("exporteur", "partner", "tradeflow", "price")
```

I used the igraph package to display the trade flows.

```
library(igraph)
mydata.igraph <- graph.data.frame(mydata)
plot(mydata.igraph)
```

My questions:
1. How can I add the value and the price to every "tradeflow arrow"?
2. How to specify options for value and price (fontsize, color and so on)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. We have to assume you have read `?igraph`, and tried arguments `label`, `label.font`, `label.color` et c. "parameters for edges have prefix ‘edge.’".

Comment: Ok, thanks. My solution: `E(mydata.igraph)$label <- mydata[,3]`. This adds to every trade flow the corresponding value. But I have another problem now: the labels are overlapping. Can you give me another hint? Thanks